# Azure-Devops pipeline not building automatically when yaml file pushed along with code

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to implement azure automatic pipeline build with azure-pipelines.yaml

i have tried the below methods in order to get it work.

- azure-pipelines.yaml(yml)
- .vsts-ci.yml(yaml)
- .azure-pipelines.yaml(yml)

But when I'm trying with UI it's detecting.
Is it possible to build auto build pipeline in Azure-devops?

Comment: Please provide us with some (relevant) code, or in this case a part of the build pipeline. Have you specified a [`trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) for your pipeline?

Comment: I have followe d this blog https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-pipeline-is-not-created-automatically/906198
And you can find the codes in https://github.com/vinayhegde105/azure-yaml.git
In my project, I'm using AzureGit as Source control.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: It used to work with "azure-pipeline.ymls", the pipeline appeared in "All pipelines" and was ready to be started manually or automatically on the next commit. I can't get it to work anymore, though...

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a GitHub repo in an Azure DevOps pipeline, there's some stuff you need to setup.

> Azure Pipelines can automatically build and validate every pull request and commit to your GitHub repository. This article describes how to configure the integration between GitHub and Azure Pipelines.
>
> If you're new to Azure Pipelines integration with GitHub, follow the steps in [Create your first pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops) to get your first pipeline working with a GitHub repository, and then come back to this article to learn more about configuring and customizing the integration between GitHub and Azure Pipelines.

Source: [Build GitHub repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

If you explicitly need a DevOps Pipeline to build your GitHub repo, have a look at the article linked to above. Otherwise think about either working with GitHub Actionshttps://github.com/features/actions on your GitHub repo, or hosting your repo in [Azure Repos](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/).

Comment: I'm Using azure repo as source control and all codes are in the azure repos with azure-pipelines.yaml!!!!!
is it possible to create new build when i push azure-pipelines.yaml to the repo!?
we are not linking ADO and github and everything is in azure devops only.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your repository is located you should place your **.yml** file inside this repository in order to work with the trigger. You should also use the **trigger** keyword.

Then when you create your pipeline, you will choose Github, Azure Repos Git, whatever you use and select existing pipeline.

[image: pipeline selection]

If you use the starter pipeline of Azure Devops, the pipeline will trigger out of the box when a commit is pushed on the **main** branch.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

You can change **main** to which ever branch you need to trigger automatically.